# Are href="{{ url('articles') }}" and href="{{ route('articles') }}" doing the same thing?

Tags: laravel

I have this code

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('articles') }}">My articles</a>
```

it works fine, but I've seen in the documentation and other refs that we can use route instead of url():

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('articles') }}">My articles</a>
```

but it didn't work for me.
what is the difference between them and why it didn't work for me?
here is my route definition:

```
Route::resource('articles', ArticlesController::class); // generated by artisan command
```

Comment: You can find all the details in their documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes
In short: One needs to pass the routes name, in your case `articles.index` to the `route()` method. This is a helper and will afterwards generate the correct URL. If you don't have a named route you need to use the  `url()` method.
It is best practice to use named routes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both generate URLs under the hood. The difference being [`url`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-url) generates it based on the provided path whereas [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-route) generates it based on the name of the route provided.

The reason your `route` has not worked is because there is no route named `articles`. `Route::resource` generates the routes for you, but the `route` you most likely want to reference is `articles.index`.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('articles.index') }}">My articles</a>
```

You can use `php artisan route:list` to see all the available `routes` in your application.

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to call `{{ route('articles.index') }}` when using a resource route.

[Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) has all the names for resource routes

Edit: depending on how you setup your routes they will *not* do the same:

`{{ url('articles') }}` calls the *URL* `/articles`.

If you have a *named route* defined as:

`Route::get('/myarticles', [ArticleController::class, 'index'])->name('articles');` then `{{ route('articles') }}` will call the URL `/myarticles`.

Manual for [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes)